# How to undo visual studio updates

Tags: visual-studio, updates

Yesterday I updated my Visual Studio 2017 version 15.x.x
to visual studio 15.7.3 .
Is possible to return to the version I had before this new?
The problem is that I don't know the exact version of visual studio I have usded these months

Answer (score 0):

You can install an earlier version of VS 2017.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017

Comment: thanks, I've already seen this. The problem was I don't know the exact number of mine previous version. I didn't want to rebuild ext. libraries but well, I did. Question is(for the future) : is a way to find your previous version of VS?